# How can I prevent the "The process can not access the file 'Bla.txt' because it is being used by another process" error?

Tags: c#, file-io, process, io

I've got this code to write a byte array to a text file for debugging purposes:

```
string path = @"\LOG\WrittenData.txt";
. . .
if( bWriter != null )
{
    if( bWriter.BaseStream.CanWrite )
    {
        bWriter.Write( readbuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead );
        //TODO: Remove after testing
        WriteByteArrayToFile(path, readbuffer);
    }
}
```

. . .

```
public static bool WriteByteArrayToFile(string fileName, byte[] readBuffer) 
{ 
    try
    {
        FileStream _FileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
                _FileStream.Write(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    } 
    return false;
}
```

...unfortunately, it fails with the err msg in the title.

### UPDATE

Okay, I tried to try the suggestion about putting a close in a finally. However, it won't compile! What is shown below does, what is commented out does not! What!?!

```
try
{
    // Open file for reading. // changed from FileMode.Create to FileMode.Append
    System.IO.FileStream _FileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
    _FileStream.Write(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length);
    _FileStream.Close();
}   
finally
{
    ;//_FileStream.Close(); <-- won't compile - "The type or namespace name '_FileStream' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"
}
```

Comment: Close the application that has "bla.txt" open, or call `Close()` on the object in your c# program that has "bla.txt" open.

Comment: The only app that has it open is the one generating the err msg.

Comment: Is `bWriter` holding the file open?  Wrap that first block of code in a `using` statement.

Comment: Add finally clause with _FileStream.Close()

Comment: Yeah, what you're trying to do won't work.  It's not clear from your code what you are trying to do.  What is clear is that you can't write to the same file using two different objects that are both trying to lock the file for write.

Comment: The only code I added is the "string path" line, the "WriteByteArrayToFile()" method, and the call to that method.

Comment: @nsconnector: Updated my post with your suggestion.

Comment: I think your new version doesn't work because the scope of filestream is the try block. Pull the variable declaration outside the try and it should compile.

Comment: @Xav: Yeah, that one's bitten me before; I've got the memory of a sieve!

Comment: @nsconnector: Make your suggestion an answer, and I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that your own program is keeping the file open.  Make sure you are closing the file every time you open it?

If you are not sure of this please post more code, from what you posted it looks like you are opening the same file twice without closing it.

You have `bWriter` and then you open it again in `WriteByteArrayToFile` without a close.

Comment: Its a comment, rather than an answer

Comment: Maybe, unless I'm right (which it looks like from the code shown) in this case it looks like a comment but is a solution.

Comment: @Ravi - I re-wrote it to look like an answer (hat tip).

Comment: I believe 'bWriter' is in memory not accessing the file until 'WriteByteArrayToFile' is called

Comment: @user2140261 - In the comments the OP said his is the only program, so it must be his program that has it open, it is bWriter or some other place which is not shown.

Answer (score 1):

Something clearly has that file open in a mode that does not permit the file to be written to.  Close that thing.

If you're not sure what process has it open, you can find that out with Process Explorer

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx